# How to XML to Php

Tags: php, xml

How to write php so I know the link here? 
There will always be different links

```
<response>
<redirect>
http://www.example.com/
</redirect>
<code>0</code>
<description>OK</description>
</response>
```

Comment: If your XML data is really this simple a Regular Expression might do the job. Failing that, [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) will do it.

Answer (score 1):

try [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$xml ='<response>
<redirect>
http://www.example.com/
</redirect>
<code>0</code>
<description>OK</description>
</response>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->redirect; // http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: need to being fast :)

Answer (score 0):

simplexml_load_string

This should answer all your questions...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM+Xpath:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<response>
  <redirect>http://www.example.com/</redirect>
  <code>0</code>
  <description>OK</description>
</response>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(/response/redirect)'));
```

Output:

```
string(23) "http://www.example.com/"
```